# Зачем уведомление о поднятии Духом?

Tags: поддержка, faq, дух-сообщества

[image: Скриншот]

1. Зачем нужно это уведомление (не поднятие вопросов, а именно уведомление)?
2. Как долго оно будет висеть?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Причиной добавления этого баннера в поднятые Духом сообщения явился [пост на SE.Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279203/how-can-we-make-the-purpose-of-community-bumping-more-obvious). Основная суть идеи поднятия вопроса как раз изложена в содержании упомянутого баннера: воздать должное ответам на поднятый вопрос, т.е. чтобы ответ ушёл либо в плюс, либо в минус. Чтобы это было более очевидным - добавили баннер.

Про длительность отображения баннера информации у меня, к сожалению, нет. Вполне допускаю, что он исчезнет только после добавления нового ответа, или изменения суммы голосов по существующему.

Нашелся [комментарий](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288139/bumped-to-the-homepage-notices-should-link-to-community-users-profile#comment935635_288195) участника [Oded ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) по поводу сроков отображения баннера. Если я правильно понял, он будет висеть 3 дня или до проявления другой пользовательской активности в вопросе (что наступит раньше).

Comment: Действительно, исчезает, если ответ запостить.